# Android Studio - put a Sound to a PageTurnLayout Library

Tags: java, android

I am building an app which shows a couple of images like a book, so I can swipe to turn the pages using a Library called book-animation https://github.com/briangriffey/book-animation. Everything works great so far but now I would like to put a mp3 sound the moment when the page flips. Problem is I don´t have any Idea how to do it.
Maybe I should put some MediaPlayer code into the Library, but I just get errors. Here's the code:

```
package com.briangriffey.notebook;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.LinearGradient;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class PageTurnLayout extends FrameLayout {

private Point mLastTouchPoint;
private Rect mTopViewRect;
private Rect mBottomViewRect;

private Paint mPaint;
private int mCurrentPage;

private int mPageTouchSlop;
private boolean mIsTurning;

private PageTurnDirection mDirection;
private float mFirstX;

private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

public PageTurnLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();

}

public PageTurnLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

public PageTurnLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();

}

private void init() {
    setWillNotDraw(false);
    mPaint = new Paint();

    mBottomViewRect = new Rect();
    mTopViewRect = new Rect();

    mPageTouchSlop = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.touch_start_padding);
}

protected boolean isTouchAPageTurnStart(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (ev.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        return false;

    return isTouchNearEdge(ev);

}

protected boolean isTouchNearEdge(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (Math.abs(ev.getX() - getMeasuredWidth()) < mPageTouchSlop)
        return true;
    else if (ev.getX() < mPageTouchSlop)
        return true;

    return false;
}

protected PageTurnDirection getPageTurnDirection(MotionEvent ev) {
    if(mFirstX - ev.getX() == 0.0f)
        return null;

    PageTurnDirection direction = mFirstX - ev.getX() > 0 ? PageTurnDirection.LEFT : PageTurnDirection.RIGHT;
    return direction;
}

protected boolean shouldTurn() {
    if(mDirection == null)
        return false;

    if(mDirection == PageTurnDirection.LEFT && mCurrentPage == getChildCount() - 1)
        return false;
    else if(mDirection == PageTurnDirection.RIGHT && mCurrentPage == 0)
        return false;

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && !mIsTurning) {

        mIsTurning = isTouchAPageTurnStart(event);

        if (!mIsTurning) {
            return false;
        } else {

            invalidate();
            mLastTouchPoint = new Point((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
            mFirstX = event.getX();
            return true;
        }

    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE && mIsTurning) {
        if(mDirection == null) {
            //get the page turn direction
            mDirection = getPageTurnDirection(event);

            //if we shouldn't turn then abort everything and reset it
            if(!shouldTurn()) {
                mDirection = null;
                mIsTurning = false;
                return false;
            }
        }

        mLastTouchPoint = new Point((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
        invalidate();

    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && mIsTurning) {

        int halfWidth = getMeasuredWidth() / 2;

        if (mLastTouchPoint.x > halfWidth) {
            final Runnable animationRunnable = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    mLastTouchPoint.x += 20;
                    invalidate();

                    if (mLastTouchPoint.x < getMeasuredWidth())
                        mHandler.post(this);
                    else {
                        mIsTurning = false;

                        if (mDirection == PageTurnDirection.RIGHT)
                            mCurrentPage--;
                        mDirection = null;
                    }
                }
            };

            mHandler.post(animationRunnable);
        } else {

            final Runnable animationRunnable = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    mLastTouchPoint.x -= 20;
                    invalidate();

                    if (mLastTouchPoint.x > -(getMeasuredWidth() / 2)) {
                        mHandler.post(this);
                    } else {
                        mIsTurning = false;

                        if (mDirection == PageTurnDirection.LEFT)
                            mCurrentPage++;
                        mDirection = null;
                    }
                }
            };

            mHandler.post(animationRunnable);

        }
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {

    if (mLastTouchPoint != null && mIsTurning && mDirection != null) {
        View topView;
        View bottomView;

        if (mDirection == PageTurnDirection.LEFT) {
            topView = getChildAt(mCurrentPage);
            bottomView = getChildAt(mCurrentPage + 1);
        } else {
            topView = getChildAt(mCurrentPage - 1);
            bottomView = getChildAt(mCurrentPage);
        }

        int height = getMeasuredHeight();
        int width = getMeasuredWidth();

        int halfWidth = (int) (width * .5);

        int distanceToEnd = width - mLastTouchPoint.x;
        int backOfPageWidth = Math.min(halfWidth, distanceToEnd / 2);
        int shadowLength = Math.max(5, backOfPageWidth / 20);

        // The rect that represents the backofthepage
        Rect backOfPageRect = new Rect(mLastTouchPoint.x, 0, mLastTouchPoint.x + backOfPageWidth, height);
        // The along the crease of the turning page
        Rect shadowRect = new Rect(mLastTouchPoint.x - shadowLength, 0, mLastTouchPoint.x, height);
        // The shadow cast onto the next page by teh turning page
        Rect backShadowRect = new Rect(backOfPageRect.right, 0, backOfPageRect.right + (backOfPageWidth / 2), height);

        // set the top view to be the current page to the crease of the
        // turning page
        mTopViewRect.set(0, 0, mLastTouchPoint.x, getMeasuredHeight());
        mBottomViewRect.set(backOfPageRect.right, 0, width, height);

        canvas.save();
        // clip and draw the top page to your touch
        canvas.clipRect(mTopViewRect);
        topView.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();

        // clip and draw the first shadow
        canvas.save();
        canvas.clipRect(shadowRect);
        mPaint.setShader(new LinearGradient(shadowRect.left, shadowRect.top, shadowRect.right, shadowRect.top, 0x00000000, 0x44000000,
                Shader.TileMode.REPEAT));
        canvas.drawPaint(mPaint);
        canvas.restore();

        mPaint.setShader(null);

        // clip and draw the gradient that makes the page look bent
        canvas.save();
        canvas.clipRect(backOfPageRect);
        mPaint.setShadowLayer(0, 0, 0, 0x00000000);
        mPaint.setShader(new LinearGradient(backOfPageRect.left, backOfPageRect.top, backOfPageRect.right, backOfPageRect.top, new int[] { 0xFFEEEEEE,
                0xFFDDDDDD, 0xFFEEEEEE, 0xFFD6D6D6 }, new float[] { .35f, .73f, 9f, 1.0f }, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT));
        canvas.drawPaint(mPaint);
        canvas.restore();

        // draw the second page in the remaining space
        canvas.save();
        canvas.clipRect(mBottomViewRect);
        bottomView.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();

        // now draw a shadow
        if (backShadowRect.left > 0) {
            canvas.save();
            canvas.clipRect(backShadowRect);
            mPaint.setShader(new LinearGradient(backShadowRect.left, backShadowRect.top, backShadowRect.right, backShadowRect.top, 0x44000000, 0x00000000,
                    Shader.TileMode.REPEAT));
            canvas.drawPaint(mPaint);
            // canvas.drawColor(0xFF000000);
            canvas.restore();
        }
    } else {
        getChildAt(mCurrentPage).draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: check if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296465/how-to-play-short-sounds-while-swiping-pages

Comment: Please edit your question after you have read ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.